# How to stop or cancel download in chrome android

Tags: chrome-for-android, downloading

How to stop download in chrome download in Android.

Answer (score 1):

To stop downloading some file in chrome you can do this:
Simply press cancel or x on notification where it shows that file is downloading or it shows remaining time, or you can longpress on that notification (if you don't have cancel button there) and press 'app info' when it opens app in app manager just simply force stop it.

Comment: Second method is ok. But first won't work for old version of chrome

Comment: @Sagar V  Yes, that's why I mentioned second method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the short way TO solve this issue.

Go to download FOLDER through Explore app or any files opening app.

Inside you will find the (current) DOWNLOADING file with extension.        .crdownload

Now you try to open the file, it will ask for "open with"
Then select any one to open the file.

Finally wait for sometime, download notification will disappear and download will STOP.

Comment: No. It won't. Since chrome lost focus, it is just paused. It will continue when you reopen chrome

Comment: Just  clear Chrome  data and cache

Answer (score 0):

I just simply "Restart" my phone. When you on data connection, the downloading will begin automatically and the "Cancel" and "pause" options will appear

Answer (score -1):

Goto to **Apps / App Manager**

Select **Chrome**

If Chrome is User Downloaded app You can Press **"Clear Data"**

If Chrome if System app, You can press 
**"Manage Space"**

Then, **Google Chrome Storage** will get opened,

Then, Click on **Clear All Data.**

Note : Please note your all data will be cleared. So Backup your Bookmarks if needed.

Comment: Your answer is correct for clearing cache for downloaded files but question is about how to stop a downloading file in android?

Comment: Why would he cleared data to stop download?

Comment: Because, there is no other option available rather than clearing data right now!